# Reference request for lyapunov exponents in continuous chaotic systems.

Tags: dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

I was looking for references which calculates Lyapunov Exponents of the continuous Chaotic systems like for Lorenz system, Rossler system, Chua's circuit. I found on searching many rigorous formulation in the calculation of Lyapunov exponents.

So is there any lucid presentation of the calculation of Lyapunov exponents.

This [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13063/lyapunov-exponent-reference) consists of the calculation of Lyapunov Exponents in case of maps, but I am looking for continuous case.

Any help is great!

Comment: The truth is that your question is too broad (in particular, it really depends a lot on your specific system), but it is fair to say that most methods are quite analogous to those for discrete time (even those involving Lyapunov functions). I suggest that you have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_exponent for many references related to your question.

Comment: will give a look@JohnB,but it was strange that finding fixed points is usually easy but finding Lyapunov exponents is not :).

Comment: Actually there is a chat room dedicated to [Dynamical systems,non-linear dynamics and chaos](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55403/dynamical-systems-and-chaos-theory) but I admit that it is not so active though,just trying to gather attention of users involved in this area or like to explore much about this.

Answer (score 3):

There is [Lyapunov Exponents](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/lyapunov-exponents/0C96D0FCA7D41027741F485A9DA629AE) by *Arkady Pikovsky and Antonio Politi*, which is a pretty thorough treatment of Lyapunov exponents in general, including continuous cases.

Answer (score 2):

A completely elementary presentation of the algorithms to compute Lyapunov exponents for ODE systems can be found in [Chaos: An Introduction to Dynamical Systems by Kathleen T. Alligood (Author), Tim D. Sauer (Author), James A. Yorke (Author)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387946772).